# Pushing elements to Vector in java

Tags: java, vector, biginteger

I'm writing my own custom BigInteger class in Java, and want to parse Integers in the constructor of my class. So question is, how can I add each digit of my number n to my vector properly, keeping the correct sequence? In other words, how can I add each digit to it like if I were adding them into the stack?

E.g. for `n = 1234` i need to add this like 1 2 3 4 to my vector.

That's what I already have:

```
class VeryLong {
    Vector<Integer> A = new Vector<Integer>();

    VeryLong(int n) {
        while (n > 0) {
            // A.push(n % 10)
            n /= 10;
        }
    }
```

There goes another problem, I need to overload constructor of the class to create an instance of VeryLong from int and long. Here is my code:

```
    private ArrayList<Long> A = new ArrayList<>();

    private VeryLong(int n) {
        while (n > 0) {
            A.add(long()(n % 10));
            n /= 10;
        }

        while (!A.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(A.get(0));
            A.remove(0);
        }
    }

    private VeryLong(long n) {
        while (n > 0) {
            A.add(n % 10);
            n /= 10;
        }

        while (!A.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(A.get(0));
            A.remove(0);
        }
    }
```

If I define `ArrayList` of `Long` there goes error in constructor first constuctor. Similarly, it's error in `add()` method in second, if i defina `A` as `Vector<Integer> A = new Vector<Integer>();`. How can I fix it?

Comment: If I am not wrong, `Vector` is considered deprecated. I would advice to use `ArrayList` instead. If you need concurrency and/or synchronization, checkout `CopyOnWriteArrayList` or `Collections.synchronizedList`

Comment: Is ```ArrayList``` have ```push()``` method (to the end of the list)?

Comment: The `add()` method will add the element to the "end" of the `ArrayList`. Do not confuse the `size` with `capacity`. "Size is the number of elements currently stored. Capacity is the number of elements that can be stored before the data structure has to restructure its internal storage."

Comment: Why not use a `Deque<Integer>`?

Comment: Casting to `Long` like you do in your code is unnecessary: `int` is automatically converted into a `long` when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By taking a quick look at [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html), there is no `push` method. However, what I think you are looking for is the `add` method, which adds the given item to the end of the `Vector` (or if an additional integer is provided, at that index of the `Vector`). In your example, this would look like

```java
class VeryLong {
    Vector<Integer> A = new Vector<Integer>();

    VeryLong(int n) {
        while (n > 0) {
            A.add(0, n % 10);
            n /= 10;
        }
    }
```

In this case, I wrote `A.add(0, n % 10);` since you want the "less significant" digits towards the end. Each successive digit added will push the existing elements to the "right" or end of the list in this case. This should solve your problem. :)

As acarlstein pointed out, using a `Vector` in this case is not necessarily recommended. Quoting from the [`Vector` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html),

> As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to implement the `List` interface, making it a member of the Java Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations, `Vector` is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use `ArrayList` in place of `Vector`.

Comment: So there I go into next problem: Intellij IDEA says to me, that I can't use ```A.add(n)``` to ```long n```. How can I fix this?

Comment: Also, I define my linked list to contain ```java.lang.Integer```

Comment: `A` is declared as a `Vector<Integer>`, which means it only stores `Integer`s; therefore, you can't add a `long` to it. If `A` is the source of the problem, then you want to change its type to `Vector<Long>` to accommodate a `Long`.

Comment: @EdwardChinaski Your code doesn't reference a `LinkedList`. Could you include your other code that contains that logic? It may be that the `LinkedList` may need to accept `Long`s as well, but I cannot say for sure.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up `LinkedList` with `ArrayList`, which was recommended to me to use in comments to question. Beg your pardon.

Comment: Ah, in that case, there _should_ be nothing else. However, I don't know the entirety of your code, so the root cause may be elsewhere, but what I suggested should solve the problem.

Comment: I stuck into a new problem, updated my question with it. Can you look at this, please?

Comment: can you look at my update, please, or I have to create a new thread?

Comment: If you have a new problem, then you should ask a new question. If you just edit your current problem, people searching for your first problem will be confused. :\